# http 301 redirect from htaccess to domain host

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following in a .htaccess file

```
redirect 301 /page.php http://domain.com/page
```

Which works fine and as expected.

I want to be able to redirect the following

```
http://domain2.com/page.php to http://domain2.com/page
or
http://domain3.com/page.php to http://domain3.com/page
or
http://domain4.com/page.php to http://domain4.com/page
```

So basically whatever the domain name is, I want to redirect to it. But the catch is I want to use a 301 redirect. Is this even possible ? Or should I be using RewriteCond and RewriteRule ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think just RewriteRule would be sufficient:

```
RewriteRule ^/page\.php$ /page [R=301,L]
```

This will cause any request for `page.php` to be redirected to `page` on the same domain.  The `R=301` causes a 301 redirect to be used.

Comment: The "L" stops additional rules from being processed.  I'm not sure if it is necessary when using "R" but it doesn't hurt.